# How to access fields of specific PowerShell objects?

Tags: powershell

Coming from a traditional programming standpoint, I've always had a bit of a struggle scripting in PowerShell and figuring out what objects have which fields. It's super easy in an IDE in most languages to just look at the object fields.

I've been using `Get-Member` quite a lot lately which is very helpful at taking a stab and alleviating this frustration. However, I'm still having a bit of a hard time. Here's an example:

Command:

```
Get-BitLockerVolume | Get-Member
```

Output:

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolume

Name                 MemberType Definition
----                 ---------- ----------
Equals               Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode          Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType              Method     type GetType()
ToString             Method     string ToString()
AutoUnlockEnabled    Property   System.Nullable[bool] AutoUnlockEnabled {get;}
AutoUnlockKeyStored  Property   System.Nullable[bool] AutoUnlockKeyStored {get;}
CapacityGB           Property   float CapacityGB {get;}
ComputerName         Property   string ComputerName {get;}
EncryptionMethod     Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeEncryptionMethodOnGet EncryptionMethod {get;}
EncryptionPercentage Property   System.Nullable[float] EncryptionPercentage {get;}
KeyProtector         Property   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector] KeyProtector {get;}
LockStatus           Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeLockStatus LockStatus {get;}
MetadataVersion      Property   int MetadataVersion {get;}
MountPoint           Property   string MountPoint {get;}
ProtectionStatus     Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeProtectionStatus ProtectionStatus {get;}
VolumeStatus         Property   System.Nullable[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeStatus] VolumeStatus {get;}
VolumeType           Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeType VolumeType {get;}
WipePercentage       Property   System.Nullable[float] WipePercentage {get;}
```

Okay great. Now what if I want to see the fields of the KeyProtector field?

Here I try this:

```
Get-BitLockerVolume | % {$_.KeyProtector | Get-Member}
```

On a system *where bitlocker volumes actually have a valid key protector field*, I can get the results, since the piped results aren't null.

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector

Name                MemberType Definition                                                                              
----                ---------- ----------                                                                              
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                          
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                       
GetType             Method     type GetType()                                                                          
ToString            Method     string ToString()                                                                       
AutoUnlockProtector Property   System.Nullable[bool] AutoUnlockProtector {get;}                                        
KeyCertificateType  Property   System.Nullable[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorCertificate...
KeyFileName         Property   string KeyFileName {get;}                                                               
KeyProtectorId      Property   string KeyProtectorId {get;}                                                            
KeyProtectorType    Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorType KeyProtectorType {get;}  
RecoveryPassword    Property   string RecoveryPassword {get;}                                                          
Thumbprint          Property   string Thumbprint {get;}                                                                
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                          
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                       
GetType             Method     type GetType()                                                                          
ToString            Method     string ToString()                                                                       
AutoUnlockProtector Property   System.Nullable[bool] AutoUnlockProtector {get;}                                        
KeyCertificateType  Property   System.Nullable[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorCertificate...
KeyFileName         Property   string KeyFileName {get;}                                                               
KeyProtectorId      Property   string KeyProtectorId {get;}                                                            
KeyProtectorType    Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorType KeyProtectorType {get;}  
RecoveryPassword    Property   string RecoveryPassword {get;}                                                          
Thumbprint          Property   string Thumbprint {get;}                                                                
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                          
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                       
GetType             Method     type GetType()                                                                          
ToString            Method     string ToString()                                                                       
AutoUnlockProtector Property   System.Nullable[bool] AutoUnlockProtector {get;}                                        
KeyCertificateType  Property   System.Nullable[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorCertificate...
KeyFileName         Property   string KeyFileName {get;}                                                               
KeyProtectorId      Property   string KeyProtectorId {get;}                                                            
KeyProtectorType    Property   Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorType KeyProtectorType {get;}  
RecoveryPassword    Property   string RecoveryPassword {get;}                                                          
Thumbprint          Property   string Thumbprint {get;}
```

How about on a system where I can't get away with this (most likely work around) solution? When no BitlockerVolume objects have a valid KeyProtector field, nothing is piped to Get-Member and it returns with an error.

**What if I just want to view the properties of an object, where I don't have valid/instantiated objects to pass to the Get-Member cmdlet?**

Comment: as far as i can tell, PoSh requires a valid object to show you those details. [*sigh ...*] if you want to see them and DO NOT have a valid object to examine, you will need to go look at the docs for that object. that means searching the MSDocs site for the type so that you can see what it's props are. you may have better luck searching for c# info since that is more likely to have deeper details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets talk about what we see.

```
Get-BitLockerVolume | Get-Member
```

we are looking for `KeyProtector`

```
KeyProtector         Property   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector] KeyProtector {get;}
```

We can see that KeyProtector is an object `[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector]`

So we can take that object and get member on it

```
[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector] | get-member
```

It will come back with tons of stuff but what you probably really are looking for is the properties

```
[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector].DeclaredProperties
```

And lets clean it up a little bit more

```
[Microsoft.BitLocker.Structures.BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector].DeclaredProperties | select Name
```

The Response is

```
Name               
----               
KeyProtectorId     
AutoUnlockProtector
KeyProtectorType   
KeyFileName        
RecoveryPassword   
KeyCertificateType 
Thumbprint
```

Comment: AHHH. Okay...I tried this without the [ ] around the object type and got errors. That's super great as that was a struggle for me for a long time.